# Understanding the search thread pool of elasticsearch

Tags: multithreading, performance, elasticsearch, metrics, datadog

### Background:

I am using Datadog integration with elasticsearch to monitor the ES clusters, one important metric which it shows on its dashboard is the no of active and waiting for search threads. Referring to [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-threadpool.html) ES docs, I understand that search threads work on a request queue in ES which is of the fixed size of 1000.

### Problem

I am seeing a lot of waiting for threads as shown in the image, but there is no rejected queue exception explained [here](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/rejected-execution-queue-capacity-1000/89954/2). So it means ES is not rejecting the requests but still search threads are not able to execute the request fast enough hence ended up in waiting status for a long time.

**Questions**

1. How Search request queue works exactly, is new request comes to this queue and removed as soon as it's picked by a thread?
2. I Know ES rejecting the request is definitely explains that ES is under-pressure but is there is any way to show that metric in Datadog dashboard, I couldn't find the relevant metric mentioned in [Datadog site](https://docs.datadoghq.com/integrations/elastic/) if not is there is any API which shows the historical count of these.
3. **Our ES cluster CPU usage is below 45 even during peak time%**, Still, we see a lot of waiting for search threads, so is it possible that our ES configuration isn't optimized? if yes, what are the ways to improve it.

I know its a board question, hence let me know if any additional information is required.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Avg CPU usage may not give better view. Check if max CPU utilization is getting around 100%. If so, you may need to optimize on ES side.